# Button can't be contenteditable when it's draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a button that the content of it can be editable and at the same time the button can be draggable. I would also like to make it resizable.

This is what I've done. As of now, the button is draggable but it's content can't be edited. When I erase the draggable part, the content can now be edited.

JS:

```
$(function() {

        $('#bt1').on('click', function() {
            $(this).attr('contentEditable', true); 
        });
        $('#bt1').on('blur', function() {
            $(this).attr('contentEditable', false); 
        });
        $('#bt1').draggable({cancel:false});
    });
```

HTML:

```
<button id='bt1'>edit</button>
```

**JFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/wuYY8/

Answer (score 1):

Try the **delay** option

> Time in milliseconds after mousedown until dragging should start. This option can be used to prevent unwanted drags when clicking on an element.

```
$('#bt1').draggable({
    cancel:false,
    delay:300
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-delay

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. It just delays the dragging, but I still can't edit the content.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UH9UE/377/)

```
 $("#content").draggable().click(function() {
     $(this).draggable( {disabled: false});
  }).dblclick(function() {
     $(this).draggable({ disabled: true });
});
```

Comment: this was going to be me follow-up answer but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Arun - Once I got into edit mode in your JSFIDDLE, In Chrome I couldn't click elsewhere in the text to edit there. The cursor seems fixed at one point. Of course, I could use the cursor keys to move around the text but not being able to use the mouse in that context is unintuitive.